# If $x_k ≥ 0\;\forall \in \mathbb N$, and $y_k$ a bounded sequence, then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_ky_k$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, power-series

Hi I'm really struggling with this proof.

For a start I'm struggling to believe it's true:

For example, if we take $x_k = \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ and $y_k = -k^3$ (which is bounded above by any positive number), then the series $x_ky_k$ does not converge?

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm being insanely stupid.

Thank you!

Comment: I imagine the $x_k$ are such as $\sum x_k$ converges right?
Because if they're not, this is false ( $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$ ; $y_k = 1$). So use the positivity of $x_k$ and the upper bound of the $y_k$ to get: $ |y_k x_k| \leq M |x_k| = M x_k $. From this you get the absolute convergence and therefore the convergence

Answer (score 1):

The result is true for a *bounded* sequence $(y_k)$ i.e. 
$$\exists M>0,\quad \forall k\;\; |y_k|\le M$$
and fails if $(y_k)$ is just bounded below or bounded above.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my stupidity, however I still have no idea where to start with this proof, could you offer any advice or strategies I can follow? Should I look up the definitions again and just try and work from there?